# Complex scenario with respect to jmeter timing

Tags: jmeter, timing

I need to test a scenario where I need to send 100 POST request at one go without any time interval and then after 5 min. I need to send 100 GET request at one go.
Both POST and GET request are in one thread group only

I tried adding constant timer but it is not helping mw with this scenario to test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add a [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) with 100 threads and desired number of loops

   [image]
2. Add a [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler and put your details there (hostname, port, path, payload, etc.)
   [image]
3. Add a [Synchronizing Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Synchronizing_Timer) as a child of the HTTP Request sampler and set the "Number of Simulated Users to Group by" to `100`

   [image]
4. With regards to creating a delay there are 2 options:

   - If you want to create a delay after the request add [Flow Control Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) Sampler after the request and set it to pause for 300000 milliseconds:

     [image]
   - If you want delay before the request add a [Constant Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Timer) as a child of the request and set pause for 300000 milliseconds

     [image]

More information: [A Comprehensive Guide to Using JMeter Timers](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-timer)